# why can't java have types as arguments?

Tags: java

why can't java have types as arguments ?

e.g. can't have Vector of reals where compiler checks type.

(example taken from http://www.ics.uci.edu/~kibler/javacourse/java.html)

Comment: ok, sorry people i think i made a mistake trying to understand java from that site, i will try the www.sun.java.com next time

Comment: sure i will accept, my net was not working , hence i was not able to accept answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that might be outdated, as now you can do:

```
Vector<Real> vec = new Vector<Real>();
```

and the compiler will signal an error if you try to :

```
vec.add(new Animal());
```

Comment: that is exactly what i was thinking...u proved it true

Answer (score 4):

Because that page is 12 years old and not very well written besides. Java actually [does have generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

Answer (score 2):

Use a collection with generics support, such as `Vector<Double>` instead of its non generic counterpart.

Nowadyas Java does support "types as parameters", or genericity. Read more on that [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/generics/). Your link is referring to ancient Java versions.

Comment: It doesn't support `Vector<double>` though - primitive types aren't supported as type arguments.